# One-Wire data transfer with a DS2401 via AVR

Tags: avr, 1-wire, codevision

I've an ATMEGA32 and a DS2401 (64 bit ROM - Silicon serial number). I want to read its contents.

Can anyone help me giving me a clue, sharing a pdf tutorial link for One-Wire communication or a sample code or something else?

Note: I use Codevision.

Comment: Welcome to this community. Unfortunately you may experience downvoting or closing of your question because the way it is exposed here shows that you made no effort to try something before asking us. I am very confident that a simple google query with "SPI Example ATMega32" would give you tons of results. Then, if something is still unclear, this is the time to ask us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ether can 'bit-bang' the protocol across the bus, or use a 1-wire I2C master device.  It's not hard, either way.

Application Note: [1-Wire App Note](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/214)

Maxim Integrated SDK for 1-Wire: [1-Wire SDK Link](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/ibutton/software/sdk/sdks.cfm)

Comment: Thank you dear friend. I'll check them :) - I am checking them :)